# AppFabric Cache won't start on boot of Windows 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, appfabric

I have a windows 2008 R2 server using AppFabric caching services to fuel an ASP.NET site.

When I restart the server, the AppFabric caching won't start with it. I have to start it manually. I've checked with the Services and the 3 AppFabric services are set to automatic.

There are sometimes when it will start, but I can't understand when it will start and when it will not. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the XML Configuration provider? There's a piece [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/velocity/thread/03a6ab4a-1dff-4490-bf63-97c1098519e3#ea13b7fc-ec2f-4501-8ea1-f25ed0ff810a) detailing how there are problems with auto-starting services and XML.

There's an **excellent** article [here](http://jamesbroo.me/automatically-starting-the-windows-server-appfabric-caching-service/) about getting round the problems with auto-start with a scheduled task and a bit of Powershell.

Answer (score 0):

We have a scheduled task that restarts the service on server reboot by triggering a powershell script. App Fabric needs to be administered via powershell and not via Services.

```
Import-Module DistributedCacheAdministration
Use-CacheCluster
Start-CacheCluster
```

If you only have one server with app fabric instead of clustered servers, replace the Start-CacheCluster with the below command.

```
$computer = gc env:computername
Start-CacheHost $computerName -cacheport 22233
```

Sometimes, in a clustered environment the scheduled task may fail if the slave server has not rebooted properly, in that scenario starting both machines seperately may help.

**References**

[AppFabric PowerShell Commands](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff718177(v=azure.10).aspx)

[Scheduling Task for App Fabric Restart](http://jamesbroo.me/automatically-starting-the-windows-server-appfabric-caching-service/)